# PHP Improve performance to execute multiple queries while reading a file with thousand lines

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to build a script where I need to read a `txt` file and execute some process with the lines on the file. For example, I need to check if the ID exists, if the information has updated, if yes, then update the current table, if no, then insert a new row on another temporary table to be manually checked later.

These files may contain more than 20,30 thousand lines.

When I just read the file and print some dummie content from the lines, it takes up to 40-50ms. However, when I need to connect to the database to do all those verifications, it stops before the end due to the timeout.

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
$handle = fopen($path, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        $segment = explode('|', $buffer);

        if ( strlen($segment[0]) > 6 ) {
            $param = [':code' => intval($segment[0])];
            $codeObj = Sql::exec("SELECT value FROM product WHERE code = :code", $param);

            if ( !$codeObj ) {
                $param = [
                    ':code' => $segment[0],
                    ':name' => $segment[1],
                    ':value' => $segment[2],
                ];
                Sql::exec("INSERT INTO product_tmp (code, name, value) VALUES (:code, :name, :value)", $param);
            } else {
                if ( $codeObj->value !== $segment[2] ) {
                    $param = [
                        ':code' => $segment[0],
                        ':value' => $segment[2],
                    ];
                    Sql::exec("UPDATE product SET value = :value WHERE code = :code", $param);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

And this is my Sql Class to connect with PDO and execute the query:

```
public static function exec($sql, $param = null) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host= '....'); // I've just deleted the information to connect to the database (password, user, etc.)
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if ( isset($param) ) {
            foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
                $$key = $value;
                $q->bindParam($key, $$key);
            }
        }

        $q->execute();
        $response = $q->fetchAll();

        if ( count($response) ) return $response;
        return false;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

As you can see, each query I do through `Sql::exec()`, is openning a new connection. I don't know if this may be the cause of such a delay on the process, because when I don't do any Sql query, the script run within `ms`.

Or what other part of the code may be causing this problem?

Comment: are you running it in the background, through the command line or over HTTP and Apache, for example.  Seems like a better fit for a background process.

Comment: Certainly I would not connect to the Database inside of the loop, you should save the connection to a class property or what have you and re-use it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix This is running on the background, via cron job. I mean, the cronjob call this php file to execute this function, but it also can be called manually (when and if needed - not so common to happen), or during this test phase, where I'm still building the script, then I'm running manually via xhr request

Comment: Right but how do you call it in cron, with just `php {path to php file}` or -via- curl.  If you use CURL from cron you might as well put it in the browser.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix At the momment, didn't get to this point yet, but it's problaby going to be via `php path/...`. Right now, I'm calling this function via the browser, calling the php function from a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make your function like this, 
to avoid multiple connects and also o get rid of useless code.

```
public static function getPDO() {
    if (!static::$conn) {
        static::$conn = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host= ....'); 
    }
    return static::$conn;
}
public static function exec($sql, $param = null) {
    $q = static::getPDO()->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($param);
    return $q;
}
```

then create unique index for the `code` field

then use a single INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query instead of your thrree queries

you may also want to wrap your inserts in a transaction, it may speed up the inserts up to 70 times.

Comment: What do you mean with "useless code" I saw you remove those lines related to the `bindParam`. But don't I need to use them when running queries like this `insert into table (name) VALUE (:name);`? It's also not clear what you mean by "inserts in a transaction", can you explain?

Comment: nope you don't. just put your $param into execute(), as shown above.